# Use SQL Server CE 4.0 multiuser and different processes

Tags: c#, sql, database, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

I searched the WWW and found different answers. sometimes I read articles about the SQL Server CE 4.0 and the multiuser ability. But I can not use it with different processes or on different machines at the same time. Unfortunately, I used SQL Server CE and now I need exact that feature. Is there a way to do it? Or is the only way to use a SQL Server Express edition or another file base db like sqlite to avoid a complete code change?

Update: yes, all users need to read and write!

Thanks for any suggestions!

tro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL Server Express (or any other edition), not a filebased database for this scenario.

Comment: +1 that's the only sensible way to go in a consistently multi-user environment